# Rate Limit using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use the twitter API Tweepy to crawl and store Twitter data in a fast/scalable way. I'm most interested in follower/following relationships. Is there a way for me to achieve this faster than I currently am? It seems like with the 15 minute refresh period I can only store maybe a dozen connections per 15 minutes. The tweepy.Cursor line seems to be the bottleneck.

```py
for iters in range(20):
    nameSearching = namesToSearch[0]
    print("getting followers of " + nameSearching)
    for id in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name='elonmusk').items(bfs_value):
        print(id)
        ids.append(id)
    print("ids loaded")
    namesToSearch.pop(0)
    nodeSearching = nodemap[nameSearching]
```

Comment: You can only make 15 calls in a 15 minute window using the followers API - that's the fixed rate limit. You'll have to be patient for larger followings.